# Print statement of all the class instance method are printing at last?

Tags: c++, class, oop, instance

I've defined a printList() method inside the class LinkedList which prints out all the data in the linkedlist. After printing all elements of the current list instance it prints out the statement "list printed" . Now after creating three instances of the class LinkedList and calling printList on each one by one, the elements of all three instances printed and then  "list printed" and changes line is printing three time. Can anyone please explain the reason behind this?

**Class Definition:**

```
 class Node{
    public:
    int data;
    Node* next;
    Node(int data){
        this->data = data;
        next = NULL;
    }
 };

 class LinkedList{
    public:
    Node* head;
    LinkedList(){
        head==NULL;
    }

    void push(int data){
        Node* temp = new Node(data);
        temp->next = head;
        head = temp;
    }

    void printList(){
        Node* temp = head;
        while(temp){
            cout<<temp->data<<" ";
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        cout<<"list printed"<<endl;
    }
 };
```

**Driver Program:**

```
LinkedList ll1;
    ll1.push(7);
    ll1.push(5);
    ll1.push(3);
    ll1.push(1);
    LinkedList ll2;
    ll1.push(8);
    ll1.push(6);
    ll1.push(4);
    ll1.push(2);
    LinkedList ll3;
    ll1.push(11);
    ll1.push(10);
    ll1.push(9);
    ll1.push(0);
    ll1.printList();
    ll2.printList();
    ll3.printList();
```

**Output:**

```
0 9 10 11 2 4 6 8 1 3 5 7 list printed
list printed
list printed
```

Comment: Because you "push" *all* values into `ll1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please update your code as below

```
LinkedList ll1;
    ll1.push(7);
    ll1.push(5);
    ll1.push(3);
    ll1.push(1);
    LinkedList ll2;
    ll2.push(8);
    ll2.push(6);
    ll2.push(4);
    ll2.push(2);
    LinkedList ll3;
    ll3.push(11);
    ll3.push(10);
    ll3.push(9);
    ll3.push(0);
    ll1.printList();
    ll2.printList();
    ll3.printList();
```

Comment: this is what you want to achieve

Comment: Please tell us what you changed from the code shown by the OP, and why you did that change. Also please read about [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). And note that code-only answers (without any explanation about the code or what it does and why) is discouraged.